# In the json, Use nil or do not use this key which is better?

Tags: json, api, null

Design webapi,

returned json data if a key does not exist,

Use null or do not use this key which is better?

For example:

```
{ "Id": "001", "name": "a", "addr": null}
```

or

```
{ "Id": "001", "name": "a"}
```

Clients have ios, android, web

Answer (score 0):

its a better that you not use key for those which are returning null or empty value. preferable is that you use `{ "Id": "001", "name": "a"}`